# Kotlin custom exception with multiple parameter

Tags: rest, kotlin, exception

So I want to throw an exception. But it contains more than just a String. something like this

```
class SomeException(
  val message : String,
  val someEnum : Emum,
  val customObject : CustomObject
):
```

What should I extend it to? And is this even possible? I mean this exception is thrown in between microservices. throwing exceptions in rest calls should only have a string as message in it?

Comment: The structure of your exceptions totally depends on what your needs are. Mine for example always contain a `code: String` a `userMessage: String` (something that can be displayed to the end-user) and a `developerMessage: String` (further and more technical info for developers). If you're in Kotlin then extending `Exception` is fine. Maybe `RuntimeException` if you're also dealing with Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
data class SomeException(
  override val message: String,
  val someEnum : Emum,
  val customObject : CustomObject
) : Exception(message)
```